# C# Round Value of a Textbox

Tags: c#, rounding

I have a small calculator that I am creating in C# (Sharp Develop). The user enters two values and the code returns the third. I am having trouble rounding the third value once it is returned. I have been through a couple of forums and the msdn site and I understand the code that is posted there, but I cant seem to make it work in my situation. Can anyone provide a little help? Reference the code below.

```
int y; 
decimal x, z;
x = int.Parse(tb2_fla.Text);      
y = int.Parse(tb2_e.Text);
z = (x * y * 1.732050808m) / 1000;  
tb2_kva.Text = z.ToString();
```

I welcome both assistance and criticism
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Math.Round()

```
tb2_kva.Text = Math.Round(z, # Places).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx). Or, since you're going into a string, you could use either the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), or the [Custom ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

```
Math.Round(z, 2).ToString();
z.ToString("0.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

Could Math.Round(z, nrofdecimals) be the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Math.Round function.

Answer (score 0):

Look up [Numeric Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) in the help. Something like:

```
tb2_kva.Text = String.Format("{0:d2}", z);
```

to format to 2dp